# SQL keep rows that include change in a subset of the columns

Tags: sql, distinct

I have the following table

| var1 | time | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 1 | a |
| val1 | 2 | a |
| val1 | 3 | a |
| val1 | 4 | a |
| val2 | 5 | a |
| val1 | 6 | a |
| val3 | 1 | b |
| val4 | 2 | b |
| val4 | 3 | b |
| val5 | 4 | b |

And I wish to remove all the rows with repeating values in `var1` and `var2` keeping changes in at least one of them. Sorry for the unclear explanation, instead, here is an example of how the desired table will be:

| var1 | time | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | 1 | a |
| val2 | 5 | a |
| val1 | 6 | a |
| val3 | 1 | b |
| val4 | 2 | b |
| val5 | 4 | b |

Lastly, is there a way to know how much space this table will take *before* executing the query?

EDIT: fixing variables' names in the tables

Comment: please amend your question to clarify "with repeating values in var1 and var2", because in the sample table you do not have var2

Comment: In the expected output, `val1, a` is repeated, one for time 1 and one for time 6. is that a typo or intended?

Comment: Hi, this is intended, I want to track those changes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, you could try the difference between two row numbers to solve it as the following:

```
WITH define_groups AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var2 ORDER BY time) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var1, var2 ORDER BY time) grp
  FROM table_name
),
row_numbering AS
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY var2, grp ORDER BY time) rn
  FROM define_groups
)
SELECT var1, time, var2
FROM row_numbering
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY var2, time
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/op3w8Ftd).